# Building Wheel for pycryptodome

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel, pycryptodome

I'm installing some packages from an inherited requirements.txt file and it errors out. I've drilled down to the specific package and it's pycryptodome. I can run this without issue:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

But I need a non-current version for dependency issues, 3.4.0 > versions >= 3.3.1 specifically, and now I'm having trouble running this command:

```
pip install pycryptodome==3.3.1
```

Error:

```
Collecting pycryptodome==3.3.1
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.3.1.tar.gz (3.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycryptodome
  Building wheel for pycryptodome (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Full Error (redacted a couple things):

```
command: 'c:\...\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vg9qpnv9\\pycryptodome_9e8bb9b16aac4d9980f22a903b99a966\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vg9qpnv9\\pycryptodome_9e8bb9b16aac4d9980f22a903b99a966\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_aaaf9u0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\...\venv\include\site\python3.7\pycryptodome'
         cwd: C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vg9qpnv9\pycryptodome_9e8bb9b16aac4d9980f22a903b99a966\
    Complete output (220 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ChaCha20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Salsa20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ccm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cfb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ctr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_eax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_gcm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ocb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ofb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_openpgp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_siv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\BLAKE2b.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\BLAKE2s.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\CMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\keccak.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD160.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA3_224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA3_256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA3_384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA3_512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHAKE128.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHAKE256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\IO\PEM.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\IO\PKCS8.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\IO\_PBES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\IO\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\IO
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\SecretSharing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\DSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\strxor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\Math\Numbers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\Math\Primality.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\Math\_Numbers_gmp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\Math\_Numbers_int.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\Math\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\Math
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ChaCha20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_OCB.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Salsa20.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\loader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_BLAKE2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_CMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_keccak.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD160.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA3_224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA3_256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA3_384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA3_512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHAKE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\IO\test_PBES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\IO\test_PKCS8.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\IO
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\IO\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\IO
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_SecretSharing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_import_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_import_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\nist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_dss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Padding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_strxor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Math\test_Numbers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Math\test_Primality.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Math
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Math\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Math
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-224.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-256.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-384.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-512.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHAKE128.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3\ShortMsgKAT_SHAKE256.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\SHA3
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_224.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_256.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_384.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_512.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\LongMsgKAT_224.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\LongMsgKAT_256.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\LongMsgKAT_384.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\LongMsgKAT_512.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ShortMsgKAT_224.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ShortMsgKAT_256.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ShortMsgKAT_384.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak\ShortMsgKAT_512.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\keccak
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s\blake2s-test.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s\tv1.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s\tv2.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2s
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b\blake2b-test.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b\tv1.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b\tv2.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_vectors\BLAKE2b
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\DSA
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\DSA\FIPS_186_3_SigGen.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\DSA
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\DSA\FIPS_186_3_SigVer.rsp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\DSA
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5\SigGen15_186-2.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5\SigGen15_186-3.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5\SigVer15_186-3.rsp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-v1.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigGenPSS_186-2.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigGenPSS_186-3.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigVerPSS_186-3.rsp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\...\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vg9qpnv9\\pycryptodome_9e8bb9b16aac4d9980f22a903b99a966\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vg9qpnv9\\pycryptodome_9e8bb9b16aac4d9980f22a903b99a966\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\..\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_aaaf9u0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\...\venv\include\site\python3.7\pycryptodome' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried updating pip to the latest version? And what does the log says?

Answer (score 0):

The binary wheel for pycryptodome 3.3.1 is only available for Python 3.5, which was the most recent at that time.

Your command is failing because `pip` is trying to compile it from sources, but you need to have MSVC installed for that. Instructions are here:

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-from-sources-python-3-5-and-newer